# Inserting duplicated data

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm trying to make an authentication system for Phoenix based on the Guardian package. Almost everything is OK except that when I create a new users (signing up) that user is inserted twice:

```
skeleton_dev=# Select * from users;
 id | name |   email   |                      encrypted_password                      | password |     inserted_at     |     updated_at      
----+------+-----------+--------------------------------------------------------------+----------+---------------------+---------------------
  1 | pj   | pj@pj.com | $2b$12$M2WNdw5mJkUzirwbReKT0ux1HgLFcouq.SEOWEz5dDswCWI4i/uoW |          | 2015-09-11 09:55:08 | 2015-09-11 09:55:08
  2 | pj   | pj@pj.com | $2b$12$zqHStaEXNwpVoyg8StYwT.U3BEOyZDq1tsTIA.cjzlZYsuwzL4e7u |          | 2015-09-11 09:55:09 | 2015-09-11 09:55:09
(2 rows)
```

I think the problem must be in the controller but I can't find anything strange:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = User.create_changeset(%User{})
    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    changeset = User.create_changeset(%User{}, user_params)

    if changeset.valid? do
      user = Repo.insert(changeset)

      conn
      |> put_flash(:info, "User created successfully.")
      |> Guardian.Plug.sign_in(user, :token, perms: %{ default: Guardian.Permissions.max })     #------ Autenticação ----------
      |> redirect(to: user_path(conn, :index))                                                  #------ Autenticação -------------
    else
      render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: It is impossible to know with only that code snippet. Also, you should add a unique_constraint for the email field in your database. What is your `create_changeset` function doing?

Comment: Thank you José. I though it could be something obvious (because I'm a newcomer). As such I'm going to spend some more time trying to find it and let you know.

Comment: Sorry. create_changeset does nothing special...: def create_changeset(model, params \\ :empty) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(name email password))
  end

Comment: @José Valim Someone else that was experiencing the same problem using Guardian found it: we were using in our controllers "plug :action"...Removing it solved this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was using in my controller the `plug :action`. This plug runs the controller action again and that's why it was being inserted twice in the database.
Getting rid of the `plug :action` solves it.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue which this solution solved.